# Ballot problem but the probability that candidate B is ahead of candidate A

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

Alice and Bob are running for office. Alice receives *a* votes and Bob receives *b* votes, where *a>b*. The votes are counted one at a time. What is the probability that sometime during the counting Bob is ahead of Alice?

The ballot theorem tells you the probability that Alice is strictly ahead of Bob. However, this question essentially asks the opposite. Would the answer just be 1 minus the probability that Alice is strictly ahead of Bob? Or am I oversimplifying this? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the answer is given by $1$ minus the probability that at any time Alice is ahead of Bob.

Comment: Your method does not quite work. Just because Alice isn't strictly ahead of Bob doesn't guarantee that at some point Bob was ahead of Alice. They could have been tied, such as the case of 5 votes going in the order $AABBA$

Comment: A routine variant of the [ballot problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) allows for ties.  Your problem is complementary to that.